# Error moving SQL query from Postgres to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, mariadb

This is part of a query which works fine in PostgreSQL (in a Django app):

```
CASE WHEN abc.name = 'foo bar'
    AND user.first_login <= (now() - interval '{new_user_interval} day') THEN 0
    ELSE COALESCE(abc.rank, 0)
END AS interesting_value,
```

However, when I try to run it in a MariaDB database, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN 0\n               ELSE COALESCE(abc.rank, 0)\n          END AS interesti' at line 13"

It seems to follow the MySQL [case operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) syntax fine. Why is this error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly subtracting intervals is a PostgreSQL thing, won't work on MySQL/MariaDB.

You can use the [DATE_SUB()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function instead.

Ex: `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);`

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error was the single quotes around `{new_user_interval} day`. But see @Georgi's answer above, which I've accepted since it pointed me in the right direction.